# Sync RSS feeds on multiple Thunderbird installations and iPhone

Tags: sync, iphone, thunderbird, rss

What I want to achieve is to sync my RSS feed …

- on my Thunderbird at work
- on my thunderbird at home
- on my iPhone

I'm sure a lot of people do have the same problem. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a Server / cloud where all the read/unread status are saved. I do not know a tool / service for that kind of sync. Maybe you trust google then use reader.google.com.

Else you maybe happy using a rss to imap deskop app / server app / service. All your devices do not need a special tool - just a mail client for your imap account.

I use feed2imap for that.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to sync Thunderbird profiles through cloud service (ex. dropbox).

Comment: How would that work with an iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

For now, you have to wait until the Sync feature is implemented (if ever). Watch bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=446444 .